# link to [[importedName]], and not the fully qualified name, in scaladoc

Tags: scala, reference, scaladoc

How to make a link to some imported name (which is in another package) in scaladoc, whithout having to use fully qualified name?

Example:

file 1

```
package com.pany.pck1.subpck
class Class1
```

file 2

```
package com.pany.pck2.othersubpck
import com.pany.pck1.subpck.Class1

/**
 * Use a [[Class1]]
 */
case class Class2(c1: Class1)
```

But I don't want to have in the doc `[[com.pany.pck1.subpck.Class1]]`.

If necessary, I would not mind having a ref at the end of the Class2 doc, such as

```
/**
 * ...
 * [Class1= com.pany.pck1.subpck.Class1]
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, using `@define`:

file 1

```
package com.pany.pck1.subpck
class Class1
```

file 2

```
package com.pany.pck2.othersubpck
import com.pany.pck1.subpck.Class1

/**
 * Use a $Class1
 *
 * @define Class1 [[com.pany.pck1.subpck.Class1 Class1]]
 */
case class Class2(c1: Class1)
```

So basically, define is used to create a Macro `Class1`, which is replaced by the link `[[com.pany.pck1.subpck.Class1 Class1]]`: a link to `com.pany.pck1.subpck.Class1` that is displayed as `Class1`.

This is quite convoluted but it answers the requirement.